# VTK: transform a surface in polydata

Tags: transform, vtk, stretching

I want to select a surface from polydata(STL file) and transform(deform?) it. When you select a surface, it is not connected to the existing polydata or the surface is extracted and a hole is created. Is there a way to solve this?

I want to make it like the picture below.
(The pink color area is what you want to create.)

[Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpJs3.png)

We are going to make some changes, not all of the polydata.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question in the [vtkplotter github issues](https://github.com/marcomusy/vtkplotter/issues/99):

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer.

I tried to make changes using the vtkThinPlateSplineTransform filter, but that didn't work.
(vktPolydata-> vtkThinPlateSplineTransform -> vtkTransformPolyDataFilter ->show)

Could you tell me more details about that?